# Basic questions about field homomorphism extension

Tags: elementary-number-theory, galois-theory

I learned that one can extend the homomorphism "injection" $k\hookrightarrow  \Omega$ (algebraic closure) to a morphism $u:k[a]\to \Omega$ where $a\in \Omega$ is algebraic over $k$ such that the restriction of $u$ to the base field $k$ is the identity, thanks to the mapping $k[a]\to \Omega,\,y=P(a)\mapsto P(a')$ where $a'$ is a $k$-conjugate of $a$. Then $u$ is a $k$-homorphism over $k[a]$. If we repeate this procedure to another finite extension say $k[a,b]$ with $b$ algebraic over $k[a]$, one can extend $u$ to $k[a]$-morphisms $v:k[a][b]\to\Omega,\; Q(b)\mapsto Q(b')$ where $b'$ is a $k[a]$-conjugate of $b$ and $Q\in k[a][X]$.

Can I say that the $k[a]$-morphism $v:k[a,b]\to \Omega$ is a fortiori a $k$-homorphism $k[a,b]\to \Omega$ ? In other words, a $k$-homorphism $u:k[a]\to \Omega$ can be extended to a $k$-homorphism $k[a,b]\to \Omega$ (without considering the upgrade of the invariant field).

So in case that $k[a,b]$ is normal, does one get all the Galois group elements, $k$-automorphisms over $L$, by considering the restriction of the $k[a]$-homorphisms $L\to L$ as $k$-automorphisms over $L$?

Comment: Yes, you can say that a $k[a]$-morphism is *a fortiori* a $k$-morphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this all works exactly as you are saying.